# A property of modulus of continuity

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

I'm trying to show this fact, for a generic function $f:E\subset\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$:

$$ \omega(\delta _1+\delta_2)\leq \omega(\delta _1)+\omega(\delta _2) $$

where $$\omega(\delta):=\sup_{x_1,x_2\in E\\ |x_1-x_2|<\delta}|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|.$$

I have done this:

$$\omega(\delta _1)+\omega(\delta _2) =\sup_{x_1,x_0\in E \\ |x_1-x_0|<\delta_1}|f(x_1)-f(x_0)|+\sup_{x_2,x_0'\in E \\ |x_2-x_0'|<\delta_2}|f(x_0')-f(x_2)| =$$

$$=\sup_{x_1,x_0,x_0',x_2\in E \\ |x_1-x_0|<\delta_1\\ |x_2-x_0'|<\delta_2}|f(x_1)-f(x_0)|+|f(x_0')-f(x_2)| \geq \sup_{x_1,x_0,x_2\in E \\ |x_1-x_0|<\delta_1\\ |x_2-x_0|<\delta_2}|f(x_1)-f(x_0)|+|f(x_0)-f(x_2)| \geq$$

$$\geq \sup_{x_1,x_0,x_2\in E \\ |x_1-x_0|<\delta_1\\ |x_2-x_0|<\delta_2}|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|  $$

but from this I can't pass to $\sup_{x_1,x_2\in E \\ |x_1-x_2|<\delta_1+\delta_2}|f(x_1)-f(x_2)| =:\omega(\delta_1+\delta_2) $ because this would introduce a $\leq$ in the inequality chain, and not a $\geq$ (that is needed to conclude).

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need this fact: For all $x,y\in E,$ if $|x-y|<\delta_1+\delta_2,$ then there exists $z\in E$ such that 
$$|x-z|<\delta_1 \quad\text{and}\quad |y-z|<\delta_2.$$

Comment: @Idonknow Thank you! It is true only when E is an interval (closed, open, or half-open), but this hypothesis can be taken into account without problems for me.